# Attribute will be ignored if the JETBRAINS_ANNOTATIONS condition is not defined

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget, resharper

I am interested in using [JetBrains annotations](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JetBrains.Annotations) only during development time, and I've marked that accordingly in the nuget package.config file:

```xml
  <package id="JetBrains.Annotations" version="10.2.1" targetFramework="net452" developmentOnly="true"/>
```

I am getting this tooltip over the attributes that I am trying to use such as `[NotNull]`:

[image]

**Why do I need to define this condition if I have referenced the JetBrains.Annotations library?**

Comment: Could you share some code snippet to help us reproduce this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define the `JETBRAINS_ANNOTATIONS` symbol, your annotation attribute usages will be compiled into your assembly (and consumers of your assembly can benefit from them). But you get an assembly reference to `Jetbrains.Annotations`. (=> You should not define the package reference as `developmentOnly` to get it automatically as dependency reference when you do a `nuget pack` on your project.)

If you don't define it, assembly consumers can't use the annotations of your assembly and you don't get a dependency on `Jetbrains.Annotations`.

For details, see [ReSharper Help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.3/Code_Analysis__Annotations_in_Source_Code.html).

**Long story short:** If you are an application author, just reference the package without defining the symbol; if you are a library author, don't reference it as `developmentOnly` and define the symbol (or distribute the annotations with your code as `internal`, like [described here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2015/08/12/how-to-use-jetbrains-annotations-to-improve-resharper-inspections/)).

BTW: If you want a second NuGet package without the conditional definitions, vote for [RSRP-432171](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-432171).